# Acessar uma variavel exportada dentro de uma função ( NodeJs )

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um bot e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

```
function a (){
    var g = {
        1 : 'a'
    }
    module.exports = {g}
}
```

Eu não consigo acessar a variavel g, de maneira alguma.. Essa expressão é realmente valida? Eu tentei coisas como:

```
let valor = a.g
let valor = a[g]
```

Mas nada fucionou. Sou iniciante, deem uma luz ai por favor!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta

```js
function a (){
    var g = {
        1 : 'a'
    }
    return {
      g
    }
}

const x = a()
console.log(x.g)
console.log(x.g["1"])
```

Observe que pra retornar o objeto g foi utilizado um return, para chamar o objeto g fora da função é necessário executar a função.

Comment: Eu fiz esse teste no console do navegador e o resultado foi o esperado, porém quando eu faço isso ultilizando o nodejs no vscode, ele me retorna um erro

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'g')

Comment: Eu acabei de testar no meu VScode e deu certo. Executei no terminal node app.js  e retornou { '1': 'a' }

Comment: Valeu mano, me serviu sim.

Answer (score 0):

Tente importar a função e já executa-la

Veja se te ajuda:

```
function a() {
  const g = {
    1: "a",
  };
  return g;
}

module.exports = a;
```

E no outro arquivo:

```
const a = require("./export")();
console.log(a);
```